# reactive chart with chart.js in meteor

Tags: javascript, charts, meteor, chart.js, meteorcharts

i am using [chart.js](https://github.com/donskifarrell/meteor-chartjs) to generate charts in a meteor app.
Here is my code

```
    function drawChart(){        
        var data = [
            {
                value: Policies.find({'purchased_cover.trip_type': 'Single Trip'}).count(),
                color:"#F38630"
            },
            {
                value :Policies.find({'purchased_cover.trip_type': 'Annual Multi-Trip'}).count(),
                color : "#E0E4CC"
            },
            {
                value : Policies.find({'purchased_cover.trip_type': 'Backpacker'}).count(),
                color : "#69D2E7"
            },          
            {
                value :Policies.find({'purchased_cover.trip_type': 'Golf Annual'}).count(),
                color : "green"
            },
            {
                value :Policies.find({'purchased_cover.trip_type': 'Golf'}).count(),
                color : "red"
            },
            {
                value :Policies.find({'purchased_cover.trip_type': 'Winter Sports Annual'}).count(),
                color : "yellow"
            }           
        ]
          var ctx = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
          var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx);
          new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
}
    Template.charts.rendered = function(){
      drawChart();

    };
```

i have few helpers to display the count in html templates and it works fine whenever the counts changes but the chart is not changing until i reload the page..i want the chart to be reactive to the changes in the collection.

Comment: in html i am just using '<canvas id="pieChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>' to render the charts

Comment: How are you including the chartjs.js file in your meteor app if i may ask? thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#tracker_autorun) to rerun `drawChart` whenever reactive data sources it depends on change:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    function drawChart() {
      ...
    }

    Tracker.autorun(drawChart());
}
```

Comment: `Template.charts.rendered = function(){ Deps.autorun(function () {
        drawChart();
    });
    };
` worked for me..

Comment: As of July 26th 2014, you could just call myPieChart.update(). Documentation is here: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-prototype-methods